# What are articles?

Tags: support

When navigating to a users page, I now see "questions" and "answers" as usual but also "articles". What are these? Are preprints intended to be posted there?

A link can be found [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/173082/ben) and an image is below: [image]

For the purposes of placing the above screenshot on a user's page, attached below is a larger screenshot of my view of whuber's page on the meta site:
[image: whubers page]

Comment: Please give us a link to this page.  Our "new users" page at https://stats.stackexchange.com/users?tab=newusers has no reference to "articles."

Comment: Hi @whuber. I've added an example link and an image.

Comment: Thank you.  I have reopened your post on the evidence of the image, but the specific page you link to contains no reference to "newest articles."

Comment: Hi @whuber, the screen capture was taken on that page. It may be that different users see differently.

Comment: Yes, I suspect so!  Could you tell us where on that page this portion appears?

Comment: @whuber, i've included a larger screenshot of my view of your page. Hopefully it helps place this portion.

Comment: Thank you--that helps.  Your question was [posted on Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/371837/articles-on-mse) a couple days ago and still hasn't been answered--that's why we're all a little in the dark.  A *comment* in that thread asserts "This is a bug, and we're on it."